# How to properly post value of id and content_no in php curl

Tags: php

I have the following curl request which I will be posting to an API

```
curl -X POST \
  https://myapi/url/ \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "entries":[
        {"id": "101AB","content_no": 101},
        {"id": "102CD","content_no": 102}
    ],

}'
```

Please how do I post the value of **id** and **content_no** via curl.

**Below is my effort so far**

```
$url = 'https://myapi/url';
$entries = array();
$entries['id'] = '';
$entries['content_no'] = '';
$params = array();
$params['entries'] = $entries;
$post = json_encode($params);

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$res = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);


var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is How I get the id and content_no working by passing their values in an arrays

```
$entries[0]['id'] = '101AB';
$entries[0]['content_no'] = 101;
$entries[1]['id'] = '102CD';
$entries[1]['content_no'] = 102;
```